# Getting ready for Android Playstore

Tags: android

I have a question, If I want to upload my Android App to Market and have it not display in the Play Store until ready to go live can I do that, Something like reserve the name and game style until ready to release.

Comment: Just upload the app and save it, don't hit "publish" until you're ready.

Comment: Yeah Definitely you can do that.. just upload screen shots and "AP-NAME" and some promo information's . first set the title in and save the information's.  just have it in mind we cant use same name for two apps. so it you may have pretty awesome name in your mind.. by instance somebody have used means you cant use that name for app. so just save all the details and don't publish it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the application name doesn't need to be unique, there is no way of reserving it.

The apps will be identified by the package name your application use. So just develop your app and upload it when it is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you open the Developer Console and start entering your app details, you can click Save and not Publish.  When you're ready to go live, click Publish.  This is how you reserve your package namespace.  There is no unique constraint on app name, but there is one on package namespace.

Comment: Thanks guys been wondering about this, really appreciated. I wanted to do this to add screen shots to various places indicating something like app coming soon. Thanks again.